# Python Import as Module Error

Tags: python, module, package

I'm reasonably new to creating packages in Python and have encountered a problem which is causing me quite a headache - as I'm sure it's easy to fix.

Basically, I have created a package containing various `Tkinter` widgets. The modules in this package can should be able to be imported or executed individually. However, I can't figure out a way to make both possible.

Here is my structure:

```
/My program  
    main.py  
    /lib  
         guiframe.py  
         /tkchartlib  
             __init__.py  
             chart.py  
             barchart.py  
             piechart.py
```

Now, both piechart.py and barchart.py contain the following import:

```
from chart import Chart
```

However, when I run the following in guiframe.py:

```
from lib.tkchartlib.piechart import PieChart
```

Which gives me this error:

```
"\lib\tkchartlib\piechart.py", line 5, in <module>  
    from chart import Chart  
ImportError: No module named 'chart'
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Edit: turns out I was trying to use the module locally; so it was not working as intended. Is there anyway to make this work locally?

Comment: Check for circular imports -- that would be if module A imports module B, and module B imports module A (or module B imports C, C imports D, D imports A).

Comment: Or try doing `from .chart import Chart`.  (Notice the `.`) .  There isn't a minimal example, so it's hard to say _exactly_ what the problem is.

Comment: `__init__.py` file is missing in your current working directory.

Comment: @kvivek should that be an answer?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working and there are no circular imports.

Comment: @ Cody Piersall, your method does work. However, it doesn't allow for piechart.py or barchart.py to be run directly - so support it just for importing :/

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` file is missing in your current working directory.

Also Check whether you have `Chart` defined in the `chart.py` file. `Chart` could be class, variable , etc.

Comment: I have included this - just forgot to list it in my file structure.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems because I forgot to add my packages to PYTHONPATH. Most IDEs will do this on their own by default, but not e.g. Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't use an IDE, also; could you please expand on what you mean by this?

Comment: I don't know much about how this stuff works at all, but it might happen that your working directory will not be automatically be added to your path variable. So it won't be recognized by Python and you can not import anything.